# Is it possible to add a .local Active Directory domain to MicrosoftOnline?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, hosting, domain, local

I'd like to add my .local domain to my MicrosoftOnline subscription, if possible. Does anyone know how such a domain can be verified, since it does not register in the global DNS system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could call customer service for an official answer but since the entire point of microsoft online (BPOS) is to be available on the internets and since you already realize that the pseudo TLD .local cannot be registered the answer is no you cannot add a .local TLD domain name to an online service like microsoft online.